# Camera extrinsic parameters as dual quaternion

Tags: quaternions, camera-matrix

Does it make sense to represent the pinhole camera extrinsic parameters as a dual quaternion instead of the classical 4x3 matrix when projecting a 3D world point to the image plane of the camera?
I also need to do the inverse (from 2D + depth to 3D world) so this is why I thought this representation could be useful to save some time, as the inverse of a dual quaternion it's not too difficult to calculate.

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that dual quaternions **can't represent non-rigid transformations** well (the "rotational" part is assumed to be a unit quaternion, the translational part is essentially a translation vector - see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_quaternion)).

This means that for [extrinsic parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning#Extrinsic_parameters), dual quaternions are a good representation (albeit a bit unorthodox one). However, from your question it seems that you want to represent also the [intrinsic parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning#Intrinsic_parameters) in the same way (2D+depth to 3D and back). Intrinsic parameters are a non-rigid transformation (they contain scale, and sometimes skew), and dual quaternions cannot be easily used to represent them.